# how to know the parent tag of a given tag when using SAXParser

Tags: xml, sax

Good morning,

I have the XML file example :

```
      <root>
          <node>
               <name n="one name"/>
          </node>
          <way>
               <name n="another name"/>
          </way>
      </root>
```

when I am parseing using SAX, and when I am raeding **name** tag, how can I know that I am in **node** tag or **way** tag. Are there any method to call or I just have to keep track of the state when parseing?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to keep track of the state when parsing.